# The structure of the  module of Kähler differentials of R[[x]] over R

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

It seems that $\Omega_{R[[x]]/R}^1$ is rather big. For example, take $R$ to be the rational numbers.

We can see that $\Omega_{R((x))/R}^1$ is a $R((x))$-vector space of infinite rank. As by results from Matsumura's book, a basis of $\Omega_{R((x))/R}^1$ coincides with a transcedence basis of $R((x))$ over $R$----remember that we take $R$ to be the rationals which is of char $0$. Yet this has nothing to do with the torsion in $\Omega_{R[[x]]/R}^1$. And what can we say for structures of $\Omega_{R[[x]]/R}^1$ for general $R$'s?

Comment: If $R=k[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ where $k$ has characteristic $p>0$ and is perfect, $\Omega_{R/k}$ is module-finite.

Comment: sure? I think the module is never finitely generated.

Comment: If $k$ is perfect, any derivation kills $R_0:=k[[x_1^p,...,x_n^p]]$.  But (using our previous notation), $R$ is module-finite over $R_0$, so it is obviously finitely generated over $R_0$.  These are the only nontrivial generators of $\Omega_{R/k}$, so $\Omega_{R/K}$ is module-finite.

Comment: @Brian: This is a special case where $\widehat{\Omega}_{R/k}=\Omega_{R/k}$, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: It is a fun exercise to prove that if $X$ is complex-analytic or rigid-analytic space (allow any non-arch. ground field, including char. > 0) and $x \in X$ is point then completed stalk at $x$ for the sheaf of 1-forms is naturally isomorphic to the module of continuous Kahler differentials for the completed local ring at $x$. One likewise proves a relative version for relative 1-forms with respect to analytic map $X \rightarrow Y$. [Gindi's assertion above would be correct more generally if he used module of cont. Kahler differentials for the max-adic topology, denoted with \widehat{\Omega}.

Answer (score 2):

- If $R$ is a field of characteristic $0$, then the differentials of a transcendence basis of $R((x))$ over $R$ constitute a basis of $\Omega^1_{R((x))/R}$ over $R((x))$.

In this sense this module is big: If $d$ denotes the transcendence degree, then we have $|R|^{\aleph_0} = max(|R|,\aleph_0,d)$. Thus if $R$ is countable, we have $d = |R|^{\aleph_0}$. But I don't know $d$ if $|R| = |R|^{\aleph_0}$. Since $\Omega^1$ commutes with localization, this also shows that $\Omega^1_{R[[x]]/R}$ is very big.

- There is an exact sequence of $R[[x]]$-modules $0 \to \cap_ {n \geq 1} x^n \Omega^1_{R[[x]]/R} \to \Omega^1_{R[[x]]/R} \to R[[x]] \to 0$. Here the map on the right is induced by the formal derivative $R[[x]] \to R[[x]]$.

For a proof (thanks owk!), we use the exact sequence of $A/I$-modules
$I/I^2 \to \Omega^1_{A/R} \otimes A/I \to \Omega^1_{(A/I)/R} \to 0$, where $A$ is a $R$-algebra and $I \subseteq A$ an ideal.

If we put $A=R[[x]]$ and $I=(x^n)$, it follows that $0 \to x^n \Omega^1_{R[[x]]/R} \to \Omega^1_{R[[x]]/R} \to \Omega^1_{R[[x]]/x^n / R} \to 0 (*)$ is exact. If we put $A = R[x], I = (x^n)$, we get a exact sequence $0 \to x^n R[x] \to R[x] \to \Omega^1_{R[[x]]/x^n / R} \to 0$. Using this, take the inverse limit of $(*)$ and get the desired sequence.

- If $M$ is a $R[[x]]$-module which is complete and separated with respect to the $x$-adic topology, then the map $Hom(\Omega^1_{R[[x]]/R},M)=Der_R(R[[x]],M) \to M, \delta \mapsto \delta(x)$ is bijective. For a proof, remark that the leibniz equality ensures that $\delta$ is continuous.

I think that $\Omega^1_{R[[x]]/R}$ is a rather pathological object. But the last remark shows that it is simple free of rank $1$ (as in the polynomial case) if we restrict to complete and separated modules, which also fits to $R[[x]]$ as $R$-module.

Comment: Fixed LaTeX.  Also, this is a great answer!

Comment: The end of this answer is not quite right: the module of "continuous" Kahler differentials is free of rank 1, and the given argument shows (for $R$ a $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra) that this is the $x$-adic completion of the module of "algebraic" differentials (for $R[[x]]$ as an $R$-algebra viewed discretely).  The "algebraic" module is indeed pathological, but since it is not in the category of complete and separated modules we cannot expect to "know" it from knowing how it maps into objects of that type (i.e., the Yoneda nonsense doesn't adapt without replacing module with $x$-adic completion).

Comment: This is exactly what I meant with "if we restrict to ... modules". By that I mean that we change the category in which the universal property holds.

Comment: Martin, then to paraphrase Clinton, it all depends on what the meaning of "it" is (for last sentence in your answer): $\Omega^1_{ R[[x]]/R}$ is what it is, regardless of what modules we map it into. Like considering a non-complete local noetherian ring $A$ and its local maps into complete local noetherian rings.  That functor on the category of complete guys is represented by completion of $A$. I wouldn't say this "shows that it is complete", since $A$ isn't complete.  So best to use a different notation, such as $\widehat{\Omega}$, when considering module of cont. Kahler difftls. 

Answer (score 1):

In the adic case, when things are rarely finitely generated, what people are usually working with is the - universally finite module of differentials. A derivation $d:R\rightarrow M$ is called finite if $RdR$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Universally finite derivation is a derivation $d$ for which any other finite derivation could be obtained by composing $d$ with a linear map. Then one defines $\Omega^1_{R/k}$ to be $RdR$ where $d$ is a Universally finite derivation. For example, if $char k = 0$, and $R = k[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$, then 
$\Omega^1_{R/k} = \oplus_{i=1}^n Rd x_i$.

More details on universally finite derivations can be found at the book "Kahler Differentials" by Ernst Kunz.